# How to use Ruby and mysql2 gem to connect mysql database via TLS1.2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

I am having issues connecting to a mysql database over TLSV1.2, using Ruby and the [mysql2](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) gem. The ruby script is running on Windows. I get the following error:

```
TLS version used does not meet minimal requirements for this server. Please use a higher TLS version and retry.
```

Based on some research I believe that mysql2 uses the Connector/C library (6.1.1), which seems to be built against YASSL, which only supports up to TLSV1.1. I can successfully connect via TLSV1.1, but if I restrict the connection to TLSV1.2 then I get the above error.

It seems possible to get a version built against OpenSSL, which supports high TLS versions, but I have found conflicting information on whether that is only for the commercial version, or if that is also available via the community edition. Does anyone have expertise in this area and can recommend a possible solution? Is it possible to get mysql2 and a compatible connector which works with TLSV1.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about [mysql2 using connector/c](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#general-instructions).

Not sure where the 6.1.1 version comes from. Did you mean [MariaDB-connector-c-3.1.11?](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-connector-c-3111-release-notes/) who's release notes advertised TLS-1.3 in the openssl version of this.

I checked the centos8 binary download from the above link and its linked against the system openssl (looking at `ldd ./lib/mariadb/libmariadb.so`).

As far as I know there's no community vs enterprise differentiation here.

Comment: Ok this was an adventure in it's own rite... but eventually I was able to get the gem to use the MariaDB-connector you linked and that did indeed fix the issue. Here's what I had to do: Install the gem with these flags pointing to the Maria connector: --with-mysql-lib + --with-mysql-include + --platform=ruby. If you don't include the --platform flag, gem install mysql2 seems to default to the mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-win32 connector. Then I had to copy the libmariadb.dll into the ruby bin folder to fix the following error "Incorrect MySQL client library version!...".

Comment: Also @danblack just to answer your question. The 6.1.1 comes from the Oracle mysql-connector-c-6.1.11 that this gem seems to use by default on Windows. From what I understand it is compiled against yassl and only supports up to TLSV1.1. Behaviour on my side seems to confirm, as using the default gem install mysql2, the connection was using TLSV1.1, even though the server supported up to TLSV1.2.

Comment: I'm glad you got there @rts_carl. I'll see what I can do next year to get a consistent use of connector/c (all versions) into all dependent libraries.